# Django admin how to create custom view to redirect to another model add view?

Tags: django, django-views, django-admin

I have two models and I want to create a custom view which would redirect to another model add_view.

My models:

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['text', 'media', 'send_type', 'created']

    class Meta:
        model = Post


admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

and

```
class ChannelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title','invite_link', 'account_actions']

 
    def my_custom_view(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        !!!!HERE!!!

    class Meta:
        model = Channel


admin.site.register(Channel, ChannelAdmin)
```

I tried but for it I need self parametr from PostAdmin

```
def my_custom_view(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       
        return PostAdmin.add_view(self, request})
```